# How do I introduce new input tokens to Mathematica (so that they can be recognized by InputAutoReplacements)?

Tags: custom-notation, input, replacement

I'm trying to introduce automatic replacements by modifying my notebook's value of `InputAutoReplacements` (e.g. via `CurrentValue[InputNotebook[], InputAutoReplacements] = {"typedinput" -> "replacement", ...}`).

`InputAutoReplacements`, though, only works for things that are deemed to be tokens by Mathematica.

So, if you introduce the rule `"abc" -> "A"`, `abc` will be replaced in your input expression by `A` once Mathematica parses `abc` as a token (e.g. once you type a space or some other non-symbol-name character after it); but `"|->" -> "\[RightTeeArrow]"` will not cause a replacement of `|->`, because it is not recognized as a token.

But what if I wanted to *make* Mathematica recognize `|->` as a token? Is there any way to do that? Or is there a safer workaround? (How does Mathematica actually implement the parsing of its input, anyway?)